# Disable shortcut keys while editing a textfield?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Is it possible to disable shortcut keys while editing a TextField?

In my scenario I have:

```
myField.addShortcutListener(new AbstractField.FocusShortcut(myField, KeyCode.N));
```

I want `myField` to receive focus everytime I hit 'n'(without modifier keys), unless I'm editing a text field.

Is there a way to do this?

Alternatively is there a way to disable all shortcut keys? If this is possible I could disable them on my own every time one of my textfields has focus.

Answer (score 2):

You could add `FocusListener` and `BlurListener` to your `TextField`. In the `BlurListener` you add the shortcut and in `FocusListener` you remove it.